# How to incorporate a boolean value in a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, boolean

Suppose I want to incorporate a boolean value in some string I print out, like

```
var x=1;
var y=2;
document.write("<p>The result is "+x==y+"</p>");
```

Normally, this does not give me the requred output. Is there a method to directly print boolean expressions in the **document.write()** itself? I do not want to use if-else and then assign separate values to variables and then print them.
PS - I have just started learning JavaScript.

Comment: Do you want to output `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put parentheses around the boolean expression:

```
document.write("<p>The result is " + (x == y) + "</p>");
```

If you don't, you're doing this:

```
document.write(("<p>The result is " + x) == (y + "</p>"));
```

---

And in general, don't use `document.write`.

Comment: What do I use then? I'm relatively new to JavaScript and so far the tutorials at W3Schools have used document.write. Are there any loopholes with it?

Comment: @nisargshah95 First advice would be to avoid W3Schools unless you already know what you're doing. Second, if you're just learning JavaScript, use the console--you don't need to write any HTML.

Comment: @nisargshah95 The JavaScript console, available by default in Chrome, and maybe Firefox as well, if it isn't, install Firebug. Or use node.js.

Answer (score 3):

This evaluates to a string:

```
(x==y).toString();
```

So you can use:

```
"<p>The result is " + (x==y).toString() + "</p>"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var x=1;
var y=2;
document.write("<p>The result is "+(x==y)+"</p>");
```

Will do

```
The result is false
```